# Reusable Schema Class salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to create a stand alone component using Lightning for fetching all record types and this thought came to my mind. I wanted to query all the available record types from an Account Object. So in my init method i am doing some thing like this which works fine for now. No issues !!
`Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Account;`

But is there any way i can make this re-usable something like the below ?

```
String objectAPIName="Account";
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.objectAPIName;
```

So that i can figure out a way just to pass the name of the Object and rest will be taken care ?
Pls suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can accomplish this, via Global Describe or by dynamic type resolution.

```
DescribeSObjectResult result = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectApiName).getDescribe();
```

---

```
DescribeSObjectResult = ((SObject)Type.forName(objectAPiName).newInstance()).getSObjectType()
   .getDescribe();
```

---

I personally recommend avoiding Schema.getGlobalDescribe() because it has **abysmal** performance in most orgs (I've seen it take over 2 *seconds* in some decently sized orgs). On the other hand, sometimes people name classes after standard object names (e.g. Account), and this tends to cause dynamic type resolution to act oddly (e.g. crash). You'll have to determine which one you'd rather take a risk on: consistently poor performance or the possibility that a developer will break your code.

Answer (score 2):

Create methods as follows:

```
public static Id getRecordTypeIdbyName(String objectName, String strRecordTypeName)
    {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(strRecordTypeName).getRecordTypeId();
    }

 public static String getRecordTypeNameById(String objectName, Id strRecordTypeId)
    {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById().get(strRecordTypeId).getName();
    }
```